# Android - Remove deceleration of fling in Scroller

Tags: android, scroller, onfling

This single line which I use in my code makes the fling, but it slows down at the end.

```
mScroller.fling(getScrollX(), getScrollY(), velocityX, velocityY, 0, right - width, 0, bottom - height);
```

So how can I remove the deceleration/slowing down of the scroller.

PS: I have tried adding `Interpolator` to `Scroller` but still same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this instead which works fine:

```
mScroller.startScroll(getScrollX(), getScrollY(), dx, dy, duration);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using setFriction(0) or perhaps using LinearInterpolator?

Comment: setFriction removes the fling, and targets API 11+.

Comment: Thanks for your tip anyway!